# Iterate over lines and replace characters - python

Tags: python

I am making an api call and outputting the response as a single line in to a .txt file.

The current output in the txt file has tonnes of extra / characters in it that I need to remove I have tried to iterate through the file and .replace() the characters but have had no success.

Current file line looks like -

```
"{\"name\":\"Win Technologies\",\"plan\":\"enterprise\",\"period\":
```

My code looks like this -

```
def call_api(headers, token):

    url = 'https://api.wonderproxy.com/v0/contract'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(token, ''),  verify=False)
    res = requests.get(f'{url}/servers', headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(token, ''),  verify=False)
    
    if response.status_code | res.status_code != 200:
        
        final_res = 'Failed to Make API Call'
    else:

        contract_response = response.text
        servers_response = res.text

        final_res = contract_response + servers_response

        file_name = f'./wonderproxy{date.today()}.txt'

        with open(file_name, 'a') as outlog:

            if os.path.getsize(file_name)> 0:
                outlog.write("\n")
                json.dump(final_res, outlog)
            else: 
                json.dump(final_res, outlog)
```

As I've said I have tried iterating over lines and doing .replace() looking for a fresh approach thanks.

Comment: Have you try using re.sub ? 
text_after = re.sub(regex_search_term, regex_replacement, text_before)

Comment: I assume the API gives you a valid JSON string. You should load that into a dict using `json.loads`, extract the information you need from the dict, and then store it in a file in the format you need.

Comment: Have you confirmed that that's what the response actually looks like? It looks like you took a valid Python string and used `repr` on it, which would account for all of the extra characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't properly handle the API response.
`contract_response` and `servers_response` will be individual JSON strings.
You should load them into individual dictionaries (or whatever the data looks like),

```py
contract_data = json.loads(contract_response)
servers_data = json.loads(servers_response)
```

Then you can `json.dump` them into *individual* files or combine them in a list or what not. The way you do it the data is treated by `json.dump` as a *string*, that's why all the characters are escaped.